# Point domain to IP

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, centos, ip

I created an apache server on Centos and configured the entire environment. I've already done the part of pointing the IP to the domain and even activated the SSL certificate (Lets Encrypt) and it worked, but some things are going wrong. For example, when I click on any link on the screen on my domain, the URL automatically goes to my IP instead of continuing on the domain. The same happens when I try to access domain.com/wp-admin, it is redirected to IP/wp-admin. I think it's some basic configuration but I'm a beginner in this part so if anyone can help I'll be grateful!

Vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

for default conf file (redirects all request to your domain with https):

```
<VirtualHost IP_ADDRESS:80>
        Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
        ServerAdmin mail@example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And for your domain conf file:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
        Protocols h2 http/1.1
        RewriteEngine on
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.com:443>
        Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

        Alias / "/var/www/example.com/"
        <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

                <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                        Dav off
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```